# Failed to use Python API to query a table with a DECIMAL column

Tags: python, decimal, dolphindb, decimalformat

- DDB server version: 2.00.9.1 2023.02.20 ; linux64
- python3.7
- dolphindb package version : 1.30.21.1

My question is:

A column in the table is of type DECIMAL. When I query it with Python API, the error "Failed to read response header from the socket with IO error type 1" is reported. Then the connection was broken.

Is it because a table of type DECIMAL cannot be read by DolphinDB Python API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1.30.21.1, a new parameter *protocol* has been added to the class `session` and `DBConnectionPool` in the Python API. The supported options include *PROTOCOL_DDB, PROTOCOL_PICKLE* (by default), and *PROTOCOL_ARROW*.

Currently the DECIMAL type is supported by *PROTOCOL_DDB* and *PROTOCOL_ARROW*. Note that the returned result is `arrow.Table` instead of `.DataFrame` when you query a table with *PROTOCOL_ARROW*, so you need to specify `protocol=keys.PROTOCOL_DDB` in your session:

```
import dolphindb.settings as keys
s = ddb.session(protocol=keys.PROTOCOL_DDB)
```

In addition, DECIMAL Array Vector is not supported by all the parameter options currently.

The result is shown as follows:

[image]